# Returning file as list of lines

Tags: python

I want to add all lines of content in the file to a list, but the returned list is empty.

```
def phone_num():
    item = []
    with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
        for i in f.readlines():
            item.append(i.strip('\n'))
        return item
phone_num()
```

Comment: Where do you call the function? no need for `.readlines()` BTW

Comment: delete ‘’.readlines()‘’，but  executing the function, the result is still empty

Comment: 在交互式shell中，您可以执行，但是在Pycharm中，您需要使用“”print + function“来获取结果为什么？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
def phone_num():
item = []
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    for i in f:
        item.append(i.strip('\n'))
    return item

thelist = phone_num()
print (thelist)
```

If my test.txt file has abc\n efg\n hij\n   it stuffs those all into a list

Comment: delete ‘’.readlines()‘’，but  executing the function, the result is still empty

Comment: 在交互式shell中，您可以执行，但是在Pycharm中，您需要使用“”print + function“来获取结果为什么？

Answer (score 1):

You can make this method quite concise by taking advantage of list comprehensions:

```
def phone_num():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        return [line.strip('\n') for line in f]
```

Also consider using `'rU'` as your open mode to enable [Universal Newline Support](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/).

Not sure why your result didn't work but it is likely because the file doesn't actually have the contents you want. Try running `open("test.txt", "r").read()` and ensuring you get output. Since this is a local file you may not be reading from the directory you think you are. Try this:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

Ensure that this matches the directory where you think your file should is.

Comment: running open("test.txt", "r").read() and i can  get output,You can't use your method. Believe it or not, you can try it，ues python3.5

Comment: Ensure you are running both commands in the same environment. For example you might be running `open("test.txt", "r").read()` from interactive shell and my code from some other directory. I've tried both functions in Python3 and they work fine.

Comment: In interactive shell, you can execute, but in Pycharm you need to use the “”print +function "to get the result. Why?